# Debugging in Eclipse: opens Class.class

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When starting debugging, the `Class.class` file opens automatically and debugging doesn't work.

I would appreciate any tips.

[image: Class.class_pic]

Comment: What does "debugging doesn't work" mean? Are you debugging with a JDK? Is that class *supposed* to open automatically?

Comment: Some debug actions are related to the selected thread or/and selected stack trace element, but in your screenshot nothing is selected of the paused thread (see the tree in the _Debug_ view). Please tell what you would like to do and what you see actually happening compared to your expectations.